# Dockerizing Spring boot application for Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: docker, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a spring boot application with some properties as below in my application.properties.

```
server.ssl.keyStore=/users/admin/certs/appcert.jks
server.ssl.keyStorePassword=certpwd
server.ssl.trustStore=/users/admin/certs/cacerts
server.ssl.trustStorePassword=trustpwd
```

Here the cert paths are hardcoded to some path. But, I dont want to hard code this as the path will not be known in Mesos or Kubernetes world.

I have a docker file as follows.

```
FROM docker.com/base/jdk1.8:latest

MAINTAINER Application Engineering [ https://docker.com/ ]

RUN mkdir -p /opt/docker/svc

COPY application/weather-service.war /opt/docker/svc/

CMD java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml
```

Here, I can use the volume mount option in kubernetes so as to place the application.proerties.

How can i achieve the same thing for cert files in the application.properties?

Here, the cert props are optional for few applications and mandatory for few applications.

I need options to integrate within the docker images and having the cert files outside the docker image.

**Approach 1**. Within the docker image

Remove the property "server.ssl.keyStore" from application.properties and pass it as a environment variable like the below one.

> CMD java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war
>   --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml  -Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/appcert.jks

Now, the cert should be places in secrets and use the volume mount options with kubernetes.

**Approach 2**. No need to have -Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/appcert.jks in the docker file, but still remove the property "server.ssl.keyStore" from application.properties and do as follows.

a. Create secret

> kubectl create secret generic svc-truststore-cert
>   --from-file=./cacerts

b. Create one env variable as below.

> {
>             "name": "JAVA_OPTS",
>             "value": "-Dserver.ssl.trustStore=/certs/truststore/cacerts"
>            }

c. Create Volume mounts under container for pod.

> "volumeMounts": [
>             {
>               "name": "truststore-cert",
>               "mountPath": "/certs/truststore"
>             }
>           ]

d. Create a volume under spec.

> {
>               "name": "truststore-cert",
>               "secret": {
>                 "secretName": "svc-truststore-cert",
>                 "items": [
>                   {
>                     "key": "cacerts",
>                     "path": "cacerts"
>                   }
>                 ]
>               }
>             }

**Approach 3**.

Using Kubernetes Persistent Volume.

Created a persistent volume on Kubernetes .

Mount the volume to the Pod of each microservice (changes in the pod script file). Mounted file system accessible via - '/shared/folder/certs' path.

> CMD java -jar /opt/docker/svc/weather-service.war
>   --spring.config.location=file:/conf/application.properties -Dlogging.config=/conf/logback.xml -Dserver.ssl.keyStore=/certs/appcert.jks

I have taken the second approach. Is this correct? Is there any other better approach?

Thanks

Comment: Looks good. Using the same to change -Xmx/-Xms and the secret creation part is the same with https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#use-case-pod-with-ssh-keys. There is a way to set permission 0400 with defaultMode: 256 as in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second approach is the best one, and it is the only way if you are storing some sensitive data like certificates, keys, etc. That topic is covered in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#overview-of-secrets).

Moreover, you can [encrypt](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/) your secrets to add another level of protection.